# Rails Cocoon Gem: field for values not rendered within another field for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I use [the Cocoon Gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to add cards:

```
<%= f.fields_for :cards do |card_fields| %>
                                <% if @there_is_card %>
                                    <%= card_fields.object.buttons.build %>
                                    <%= render 'card_fields_render', f: card_fields %>
                                <% end %>
                            <% end %>
```

In my `card_fields_render` partial, I have another field for to add (or not) buttons to the card:

```
...
<%= f.fields_for :buttons do |button_card_fields| %>
      <div class="add-button-card-modal">
        <h4>Add New Button</h4>
        <label>Button Text</label>
        <%= button_card_fields.text_field :button_text, :maxlength => 20, placeholder: "Enter the text to display on the button..." %>
        <br><br>
        <label>Button URL</label>
        <%= button_card_fields.text_field :button_url, placeholder: "Paste URL..." %>
        <div class="nav-popups-buttons">
          <button type="button" id="validate_new_card_button" class="small-cta2">Add Button</button>
          <p class="remove-link" id="delete_new_card_button">Remove Button</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
...
```

Unfortunately, when the card is rendered with a button, the values are not displayed for the `button_text`and `button_url` fields.

[image]

I have tried to add `f.object.buttons.build`but it does not solve the problem.

Card model:

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  validates :remote_image_url, :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https)), presence: { message: '%{value} : please enter valid url' }, :allow_blank => true
  validates :title, :subtitle, :presence => true

  belongs_to :letter, optional: true
  has_many :buttons, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :card
  has_many :analytic_clics, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :buttons, :reject_if => Proc.new { |att| att[:button_text].blank? && att[:button_url].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Button model:

```
class Button < ApplicationRecord
  validates :button_url, :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https)), presence: { message: '%{value} : please enter valid url' },
    unless: Proc.new { |a| a.button_url.blank? }
  validates :button_text, :presence => true, unless: Proc.new { |a| a.button_url.blank? }

  belongs_to :message, optional: true
  belongs_to :card, optional: true
  has_one :short_url, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_clics, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Letter params in controller:

```
def letter_params
      params.require(:letter).permit(:campaign_name, :core_bot_id, :nb_recipients, :scheduled_at,
        filters_attributes: [:id, :gender, :creation_date_start, :creation_date_finish, :first_name, :last_name, :segment => [], :timezone => [], :locale => []],
        messages_attributes: [:id, :content, :_destroy, buttons_attributes: [:id, :button_text, :button_url, :_destroy]],
        cards_attributes: [:id, :title, :subtitle, :image_url, :remote_image_url, :button_share, :_destroy, buttons_attributes: [:id, :button_text, :button_url, :_destroy]])
    end
```

Any idea what's the issue? Maybe I should add the button using the Cocoon's link_to_add_association? The problem is it will be in the container of the link_to_add_association used to add cards, thus creating problems for the callbacks (called twice)...

Comment: Can you post your button and card classes? What are you expecting to see in the button text, do you have some default values?

Comment: I updated the answer with the card and button models. In button text, the value should be the one entered by the user in the new view. In that case I just filled with a "text" input and a random URL.

Comment: Are you sure the button is saved correctly in the database (e.g. the button has values) ? Your associations seem correct, what about your strong parameters definition? The `card_fields.object.buttons.build` will always show one empty button, which I would prefer to only add in the controller on `new` and probably not on `edit` (but your constraints could be different)

Comment: Yes the button has values, I added the strong parameters definition in the post.

Comment: Got it, it creates two button modals, I don't know why... The new one (with empty fields, hidding the one with the values). I will try to find why it creates a new one instead of just rendering it.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `card_fields.object.buttons.build` and now it works. It was generating two times the button fields, hiding the ones filled with the values.